# How make one event handler that applies to multiple controls in C#?

Tags: c#, controls

In Visual Basic I knew how to do it, but I'm new to C#, so can you guys tell me how do I make a "private void" with mouse hover that applies the same event to multiple controls? There's an example:

```
private void button1, button2, button3, button4_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     btn.Image = pic
}
```

Comment: Try something like `this.Button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.myEventHandler);
this.Button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.myEventHandler);`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just declare one event handler and point each button at it:

```
private void Common_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Button btn = sender as Button;
     if (btn != null)
         btn.Image = pic
}
```

Then in code or designer:

```
button1.MouseHover += Common_MouseHover;
button2.MouseHover += Common_MouseHover;
// .. etc
```

Answer (score 3):

When you subscribe to the event on a button, it's just a standard event handler:

```
button1.Click += myEventHandler;
```

You can use the same code to add handlers for every button:

```
button1.Click += myEventHandler;
button2.Click += myEventHandler;
button3.Click += myEventHandler;
button4.Click += myEventHandler;
button5.Click += myEventHandler;
button6.Click += myEventHandler;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
button1.MouseOver += OnMouseOver(...)
button2.MouseOver += OnMouseOver(...)
button3.MouseOver += OnMouseOver(...)
button4.MouseOver += OnMouseOver(...)
```