# C# Add event of one of the List<PictureBox> to another PictureBox Click event

Tags: c#

```
List<PictureBox> PictureList = new List<PictureBox>();

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var pic = new PictureBox
    {
       Parent = pictureBox1,
       Name = rdr["num"].ToString(),
       Location = new Point(50, 50),
       Size = new Size(25, 25),
       BackColor = Color.Transparent,
       Image = Properties.Resources.budea,
       SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage,
    }

    PictureList.Add(pic);
}
```

After I made `List<PictureBox>` global, I create another `PictureBox`.

I want to implement an event of one of the `List<PictureBox>` to another `PictureBox` `Click` event.

In order to do it, one of the `List` should be placed in a new `PictureBox`, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: I dont understand well what you want to do. If you want to make click event, you have to: `pic.Click = PictureBoxClicked;` and create new method: `private void PictureBoxClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) { }`. Tell me, do you want to use only one click function by all of these PictureBoxes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How make one event handler that applies to multiple controls in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739572/how-make-one-event-handler-that-applies-to-multiple-controls-in-c)

Comment: You need to add one of the picture boxes as child control `this.Controls.Add(PictureList[0]);`  But you instead of creating a list of pictureboxes, you need to create a list of `Bitmap`s. and assign one bitmap to the `pictureBox1.Image` property to display it.

Comment: I want to add click event to new picturebox, this event should be event of One of the List<picturebox>..
I'm Korean ..I can't speak English well..Sorry.!