# One Event for Multiple TextBoxes WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have multiple (> 10) TextBoxes that are used to store monetary values. As the user types, I want to format the input as a currency.

I could create one method for every TextBox but that means the creation of > 10 methods. I would rather create one method that multiple TextBoxes may use. For example:

```
private void OnCurrencyTextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, 
TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    CurrencyTextBox.Text = FormattedCurrency(CurrencyTextBox.Text);
}
```

However, this would only work for a TextBox named `CurrencyTextBox`. Of course there would need to be other checks for if the key is a digit etc but for the purpose of this question I am focusing on how I can apply one method to multiple TextBoxes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How make one event handler that applies to multiple controls in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739572/how-make-one-event-handler-that-applies-to-multiple-controls-in-c). You'd find it by googling for something like "same event for different controls".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cast the sender argument to `TextBox`:

```
private void OnCurrencyTextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender,
TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;
    textBox.Text = FormattedCurrency(textBox.Text);
}
```

You can then use the same event handler for all `TextBox` elements:

```
<TextBox x:Name="t1" PreviewTextInput="OnCurrencyTextBox_PreviewTextInput" />
<TextBox x:Name="t2" PreviewTextInput="OnCurrencyTextBox_PreviewTextInput" />
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Define textbox with StringFormat=C.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=TextProperty, StringFormat=C}"/>
```

Comment: This is the best approach. and If the user want a custom format then a converter can be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

sender is Control for which event is fired:

```
private void OnCurrencyTextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, 
TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    ((TextBox)sender).Text = FormattedCurrency(((TextBox)sender).Text);
}
```