# Colour multiple textboxes with one method wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

I have a method that is supposed to color the background of a textbox that is on focus(Enter)

```
 private void onEnter_ColourChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.BackColor = Color.White;
    }
```

This doesn't work, however. I checked this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44843044/one-event-for-multiple-textboxes-wpf#44843082), but I just got a NullReferenceException.

Essentially, I would like to color multiple textboxes when the textbox is in focus, with one method. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code, I have a hunch you are looking for `(sender as TextBox).BackColor = Color.White;`.

Comment: No, I changed my code to `Textbox textbox = sender as Textbox
textbox.BackColour = Color.White`
That's where I get the `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: It also sounds like sender is not a TextBox if you are getting a NullReferenceException

Comment: You should do this with a style instead. You won't get any null reference exceptions that way.

Comment: @zambonee, that doesn't work (if that was a suggestion)

Comment: @TonyLancer How are you assigning this event to the textboxes? Can you show ALL references to this event in your XAML? Can you put a breakpoint on the open curly brace of the event handler, and when it breaks into the debugger, hover the mouse over `sender`? If `sender` isn't a TextBox, you can't cast it as one. If `sender` isn't a TextBox, you put the event on the wrong control.

Comment: @TonyLancer "That doesn't work" isn't very specific. On Stack Overflow, we ask people to provide much more detail about problems. We need to know if it failed to compile, or threw an exception at runtime. If it did throw an exception, we need to know which exception, and often we want to see the stack trace as well.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: TextBox has only the property Background and not BackColor!

If you want to change the color of the focused TextBox, a simple way is, to use a Style with a Trigger.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="TextBoxFocusBackgroundStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true" >
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Brown" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

As you can see, the Trigger watches on the property IsFocused. If the TextBox got the Focus (so IsFocused changes to true), the Background will be brown.

To use this Style:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="Peter" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxFocusBackgroundStyle}"/>
    <TextBox Text="Laszlo" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxFocusBackgroundStyle}"/>
    <TextBox Text="Julia" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxFocusBackgroundStyle}"/>
    <TextBox Text="Romeo" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxFocusBackgroundStyle}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

If you already has a Style for the TextBoxes you should use that Style in the BasedOn attribute.