# Single method for multiple button backgroind image changes?

Tags: c#, button, background

I am new here. I would love if you could help me with writing a method that can change the background image of the button that is clicked.

This is what I am doing right now. As you can see I am doing it for every button each. I would love to know if there is a way to do one method that the buttons will just call.

This is for a simple Tic Tac Toe multiplayer game.

```
private void cell23_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (gameGrid[1, 2] == "n")
        {
            if (currentPlayer == "x")
            {
                this.cell23.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.cross));
                currentPlayer = "o";
                gameGrid[1, 2] = "x";
                cell23.Enabled = false;
            }
            else if (currentPlayer == "o")
            {
                this.cell23.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.nought));
                currentPlayer = "x";
                gameGrid[1, 2] = "o";
                cell23.Enabled = false;
            }

        }
```

EDIT:

```
private void AnyCell_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        switch (btn.Tag)
        {
            case "cell11":
                ButtonPressed(0,0); break;
            case "two":
            case "three":

            default: break;
        }
    }
```

Now that I have this method. How do I make when I press button with the tag cell11 to get to this code here?

Comment: What type is `cell23`?

Comment: I think the clicked cell instance is in the sender parameter.

Comment: all cell$$ are buttons if this is what you asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `sender` argument, which is (usually) set to the object that raised the event.

```
private void AnyCell_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var clickedCell = sender as Control; //Or whatever type it is

    if (gameGrid[1, 2] == "n")
    {
        if (currentPlayer == "x")
        {
            clickedCell.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.cross));
            currentPlayer = "o";
            gameGrid[1, 2] = "x";
            clickedCell.Enabled = false;
        }
        else if (currentPlayer == "o")
        {
            clickedCell.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.nought));
            currentPlayer = "x";
            gameGrid[1, 2] = "o";
            clickedCell.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: once I try to call the method in a button it gives this: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter "sender"

Comment: It's the click handler. You don't call it. You register it as your event handler. If you're trying to call it from an event handler, just pass the arguments through.

Comment: I have edited my question, could you review it please.

Comment: [How to make one event handler that applies to multiple controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739572/how-make-one-event-handler-that-applies-to-multiple-controls-in-c)